# Access - Return Random Fields and Lock Row in Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am looking to return two rows but either lock the rows so when the query is run again two different rows are returned or enter the values into the field which will then prevent the rows being called anyway.

So the code i have returns two rows for me but i cant find a way in **Access 2010** to do the above, any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT TOP 2 Referrals_Checked.Alternative_ID, Referrals_Checked.Team, 
Referrals_Checked.Checked_By, Referrals_Checked.Date_Time
FROM Referrals_Checked
WHERE (((Referrals_Checked.Checked_By) Is Null) AND (([FORMS]! 
[Referrals_Checked]![Combo49])=[TEAM_Code]))
ORDER BY Rnd(Referrals_Checked.ID);
```

Comment: Insert result set into [temporary table](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/07/20/use-temp-tables-in-your-code-for-quick-and-easy-analysis/) ;)

Comment: When are the two rows cleared and able to be selected again?

Comment: Once the user has entered a date and there name which the date would be current and name I could get from their window login id

Answer (score 0):

Add a date field to the table: TimeStamp.

Modify you query to exclude those records having a TimeStamp recorded:

```
WHERE 
    Referrals_Checked.Checked_By Is Null AND
    Referrals_Checked.TimeStamp Is Null AND
    [TEAM Code] = [FORMS]![Referrals_Checked]![Combo49]
```

Then use an update query to update that when you wish to select two new IDs:

```
UPDATE Referrals_Checked
SET Referrals_Checked.TimeStamp = Now()
WHERE ID IN (<SQL of your select query>)
```

Then select your two stamped records:

```
SELECT TOP 2 
    Referrals_Checked.Alternative_ID, 
    Referrals_Checked.Team, 
    Referrals_Checked.Checked_By, 
    Referrals_Checked.Date_Time
FROM 
    Referrals_Checked
ORDER BY 
    Referrals_Checked.ID Desc;
```